# Typecasting double arrray in matlab to int array in C

Tags: c, arrays, matlab

I am trying to write a mex function. I am accessing an array that is of type double (in MATLAB all data is by default double,isn't it). But this specific array I am working with has only integers. I want to typecast to an integer array in the mex function. Is there a way to typecast the whole array rather than doing it using a for loop.

Comment: No, an array of one type can't be converted to an array of another type using simple casting. You have to convert all elements separately.

Comment: It is simpler to cast the array in Matlab, before passing it to the mex function. Simply use `B = int32(A)`, then pass B to the mex function as `int32` array (instead of `double` array).

Comment: @Rotem You just simplified my work. Your suggestion helped me a lot